# Is $\log(z^2)$ even?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Im trying to figure out if $\log(z^2)$ (mainbranch cut) is even, odd or not both, and where exactly, my thinking is for all $z$ such that $\arg(z)$ belongs to
 $$\ [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$$ any help? (:

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: This is very easy to determine. Just check that $z\mapsto -z$ leaves the function unchanged.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Maybe your question is if $\log (z^2)=2\log (z) $?

Comment: Sorry guys its my first question here Ill get better

Comment: Hum no I just want to check if this function is even, and if so where about exactly